# How to create context menu for data-bound WP Silverlight ListBox totally from code?

Tags: listbox, windows-phone, contextmenu, listboxitem, wptoolkit

I have a classic ListBox control with a custom ItemTemplate. The ListBox is bound to a collection of objecs. How can I create a custom context menu (an instance of the ContextMenu class from Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll) and attach them to my ListBox items totally from code?

Comment: Hey TecMan, good to see you again. Normally, I would spin up a code example, but I don't have the Windows-Phone libraries on this machine. Anyway, typically, you would create a control that inherits from ContextMenu. You can just new that up and then add it to your ListBox's item source in the code behind.

Comment: @Onosa, Add an inherited ContextMenu to the ItemSource? Code, I definitely need some code!